# Как выбрать коллецию, одним из свойств которой является коллекция?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Есть две модели, они связаны:

```
class Linecategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :slug, uniqueness: true
  validates :name, :slug, presence: true #не яляются пустыми
  has_one :main_image
end
class MainImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :linecategory
end
```

Я посылаю *ajax* на контроллер и хочу получить все записи таблицы *linecategory*, и также в каждый объект этой коллекции добавить свойство `main_image`, в которое будет записан объект или коллекция объектов — картинок `main_image`.

Проблема в том, что если я получаю все *linecategory*, например вот так:
`linecategories=Linecategory.eager_load(:main_image).order('sort')`, то
ответ *ajax* будет в виде:

```
[
    {
        id: 5, name: "Гадания", 
        slug: "divination", title: "eywords-divination",
        created_at: "2015-01-11T08:47:10.000Z",
        description: "2015-01-11 08:47:10".
    },
    {....},{....}
]
```

А мне хотелось бы получить в виде:

```
[
    {
        id: 5, name: "Гадания", 
        slug: "divination", title: "eywords-divination",
        created_at: "2015-01-11T08:47:10.000Z",
        description: "2015-01-11 08:47:10".
        main_image: {id: 1, src: "images/categories_image/devination.jpg", linecategory_id: 5}
    }
]
```

т.е. уже в каждый объект добавленно свойство `main_image`.

Сейчас я реализовал так, это рабтает, но понимаю что лишние операции:

```
class AdminCategoryController < ApplicationController
  # Получить все товары GET
  def add_fields(collection=[])
    result_collection=[]
    if collection.length
      collection.each do |hash|
        hash[:array].each do |item|
          obj=item.as_json
          obj[hash[:name_field]]=item.main_image
          result_collection.push obj
        end
      end
    end
    result_collection
  end

  def index
    linecategories=Linecategory.eager_load(:main_image).order('sort')
    collection_to_add=[{:name_field => "main_image", :array => linecategories}]
    render json: add_fields(collection_to_add)
  end
```

Может быть, есть другое решение?

Comment: Вы смотрите немного не туда. Коллекция не является атрибутом и потому не показывается. Вам надо настроить вызов `to_json`, там можно указать доставание вложенных коллекций.

Comment: Спасибо, большое за посказку все получилось
`linecategories=Linecategory.eager_load(:main_image).order('sort')
render json: linecategories.to_json(:include => :main_image)`

Comment: Отличная работа! Оформите это ответом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня получилось так:

```
linecategories=Linecategory.eager_load(:main_image).order('sort') 
render json: linecategories.to_json(:include => :main_image)
```